# Hosting MUD Server at Home and connect from the outside

Tags: hosting

Can anyone please give me a step-by-step explanation of how this could be done. I have MUD source code that compiles and runs perfectly on my computer.. It creates a server locally and i can connect it using my the local ip address. I was wondering, and i know its possible. But not sure how or where to look. I want it so that i can run the server from home, and use any computer to connect to it. If anyone has a link or a nice step by step guide that would be so helpful thanks!

I have tried setting it up and doing a few port forwards, but that doesn't seem to be working. Any advice would greatly be appreciated thanks!

Comment: If you do not have a normal IP adress but use NAT (as most modern home networks do), then look up "port forwarding" an "IP v6"

Comment: What is your local machine's IP address (`ipconfig` / `ifconfig`)?  Is this address DHCP-assigned?  What port is your MUD listening on on your computer (`netstat`)?  What is your outside IP address (http://whatismyip.com)?  What firewall/NAT device are you using?  How are you testing your external access?